# Execute result set of select statement using a string variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I want to execute the result of dynamic sql select query in Microsoft SQL Server **using Script only without SSMS**.
I am looking to assign the output of SQL SELECT query that returns multiple results (Multiple IF ELSE statements with INSERT commands inside the statement) to a single string variable so I can execute that using EXEC command.

It looks something like this:

QUERY 'SQL1':

```
/* Query to generate IF statements to find duplicate and unique Policies */ 
`select 'IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [POLICY_TB] WHERE Policy_number = '
       +LTRIM(STR(Policy_number))
       +' BEGIN INSERT INTO @TempDuplicateClient SELECT [Client_identifier]FROM POLICY_TB WHERE [Policy_number] = '
       +LTRIM(STR(Policy_number))
       +' END'
       +' ELSE BEGIN INSERT INTO @TempUniqueClient SELECT [Client_identifier] FROM POLICY_TB WHERE [Policy_number] = '
       +LTRIM(STR(Policy_number))
       +' END '
       from POLICY_TB`
```

Output:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [POLICY_TB] WHERE Policy_number = 1234) BEGIN INSERT INTO @TempDuplicateClient SELECT [Client_id] FROM POLICY_TB WHERE [Policy_number] = 1234 END ELSE BEGIN INSERT INTO @TempUniqueClient SELECT [Client_id] FROM POLICY_TB WHERE [Policy_number] = 1234 END 
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [POLICY_TB] WHERE Policy_number = 5678) BEGIN INSERT INTO @TempDuplicateClient SELECT [Client_id] FROM POLICY_TB WHERE [Policy_number] = 5678 END ELSE BEGIN INSERT INTO @TempUniqueClient SELECT [Client_id] FROM POLICY_TB WHERE [Policy_number] = 5678 END
```

I want to assign this entire output to a string variable.

```
DECLARE @SQL2 as varchar(MAX)
SET @SQL2 = '--above output---'
or SET @SQL2 = Output of EXEC(SQL1)
EXEC(@SQL2)
```

In simple terms, I am looking something like `EXEC(EXEC(SQL))`

I tried using `xml path ('')` in the select query to get the output as a single value but I'm unable to assign it to a variable as `EXEC('query')` doesn't return the query results.

Comment: why do you want to do that? you can solve your issue by just executing it without all that once

Comment: Can you explain your objective of using `Dynamic Query` here

Comment: @siggemannen, I need to excute everything through sql script and batch files without using SSMS.

Comment: @Squirrel, I am trying to find duplicate and non-duplicate policies comparing the new database to old database by generating the IF ELSE statements[using Dymaic Query] in old database and run in new database. Here my challenge is how to run the Output of this dynamic query through script itself without using SSMS.

Comment: You don't need dynamic query to compare two databases, you can use `FULL OUTER JOIN` or `EXISTS()` to do it

Comment: @Squirrel, This is Step1 of what I want to achieve. Two databases are on different machines. I can't change the server names in the script as the script needs to be executed by non-developer and should be executed on all users machines without any changes to the script. Can you advise how to store select query results[one column, multiple rows] as a single value to a string variable?

Comment: have you consider using [linked server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16)?

Answer (score 1):

First, your SQL query likely has an SQL Injection vulnerability. SQL injection is a type of attack where a malicious user finds a way to "inject" an SQL script into your query and execute it doing harm to your data. SQL injection attacks are common in dynamic queries where developers concatenate user input for building queries dynamically and executing them. To avoid SQL Injection attacks, you can use parameters.

Now, if you use parameters, there will not be a need for dynamic query in your case at all. Here is how I'd write your query with parameters:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [POLICY_TB] WHERE Policy_number = @Policy_Number)
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @TempDuplicateClient 
    SELECT [Client_id] FROM POLICY_TB WHERE [Policy_number] = @Policy_Number
END 
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @TempUniqueClient 
    SELECT [Client_id] FROM POLICY_TB WHERE [Policy_number] = @Policy_Number
END
```

Please note the query above is not dynamic. It's a regular query. However, if you do need to execute a dynamic query, I recommend using sp_executesql stored procedure with parameters. First, parameters will prevent SQL injection attacks. Second, the sp_executesql stored preocedure usage with parameters will improve the performance by caching the execution plan.

Comment: Why not just use `WHERE NOT EXISTS`/`WHERE EXISTS` rather than using procedural code?

Comment: @DaleK that's an option. I just used the code sample that OP had in their question.

Comment: When answering a question you want to present the best option you can, not just a tweak to make OPs code work. And set based operations are definitely better than procedural logic when it comes to SQL.